# PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR for Dot Net Site behind reverse proxy in ISS ARR

Tags: ssl, iis, reverse-proxy, arr

On IIS server with a site behind ARR Reverse Proxy, a site works fine except sometimes I get following error:

Secure Connection Failed

PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR

[image]

We are clueless why it happens some times only. Moreover, the origin site is working fine. So it should be something related to ARR settings, but we are not sure where to look next?

Comment: try to use another browser and also use iis crypto to enable SHA [image](https://imgur.com/a/kf6eb6f).you can download it from this [link](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto)

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Thanks. Is there any doc on how does this impact? And why only on few requests ?  Any guide on this topic that we should refer? This is to understand what are we doing, and why?

Comment: Firefox doesn't support SHA 256 and above yet. you could refer this [link](https://cheapsslsecurity.com/blog/troubleshoot-secure-connection-failed-error-firefox/) for more detailed information. is your issue is resolved by enabling SHA using iis crypto?

Comment: Does this help? https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/arr-authenticating-itself-to-backend-with-client-certificate-on/ba-p/1343206

Comment: we dropped to use ARR due to this and other issues and poor support from Microsoft tech team